# Правильное выполнение запроса RxJava+Retrofit

Tags: android, rest, retrofit, rxjava

Здравствуйте. Недавно начал разбираться с RxJava. Что-то тяжело пока дается...
Есть сервер на котором есть приватные чаты(тет-а-тет) и групповые.
Посредством Rest запроса на сервер нужно выудить следующую инфу оттуда:
Все существующие чаты и диалоги:

```
Observable<List<Chat>> chats = apiService.getChats();
Observable<List<Dialog>> dialogs = apiService.getDialogs();
```

Объекты Chat и Dialog содержат переменные:

```
int unreadMessagesCount (количество непрочитанных сообщений);
int id (по этому id запрашивается список сообщений из чата)
```

Запросы на список сообщений

```
Observable<List<Message>> dialogMessages = apiService.getDialogMessages(String id);
Observable<List<Message>> chatMessages = apiService.getChatMessages(String id);
```

Как в этом случае более грамотно составить запросы используя RxJava, чтобы опросить все чаты и диалоги на предмет новых сообщений и затем получить эти сообщения в один список?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Например как-то так:

1. Получаем массив чатов.
2. Преобразуем массив оных в очередь объектов `Chat`.
3. Получаем детали каждого.
4. Результат преобразовываем обратно в массив:.

```
apiService.getChats()
    .from(Observable::from)
    .flatMap(chat -> apiService.getChatMessages(chat.id))
    .toList()
    .subscribe(System::out);
```

Если без лямбд, то `from(Observable::from)` можно переписать вот такой ужасной конструкцией:

```
.flatMap(new Func1<List<Chat>, Observable<Chat>>() {
    @Override
    public Observable<Chat> call(List<Chat> chats) {
        return Observable.from(chats);
    }
})
```

Comment: Видимо что-то не понял... 
Получил "cannot resolve method 'from(<method reference>)' "

Comment: @НиколайМедведев, возможно у вас лямбды не работают. См. дополнение к ответу