# Как делать запросы одновременно в Retrofit2

Tags: java, android, vkontakte-api, retrofit, retrofit2

В `ВК Api` имеется метод [messages.getDialog()](https://vk.com/dev/messages.getDialogs), при запросе получаю такой ответ:

```
{
    "response": {
    "count": 18,
    "items": [{
        "message": {
            "id": 19026,
            "date": 1507760699,
            "out": 1,
            "user_id": 313086824,
            "read_state": 0,
            "title": "",
            "body": "Отлично!",
            "random_id": 0
        },
        "in_read": 19026,
        "out_read": 19003
        }]
    }
}
```

Сам запрос:

```
MyApplication.getRestApiUrl().getMessagesList(count, accessToken, Constants.api_version).enqueue(new Callback<ChatsModel>() {
@Override
public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<ChatsModel> call,
                       @NonNull Response<ChatsModel> response) {

        if (response.body() != null) {

            //Действие при успешном запросе

        } 
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<ChatsModel> call,
                          @NonNull Throwable t) {
            chatsCallback.onGetChatsError(call.toString());
    }
});
```

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы при успешном ответе вместе с списком диалогов приходил еще и данные о тех пользователях с которыми был диалог, то есть данные того `user_id` чтобы имя и аватарку вставлять в списке `RecyclerView`.

Так вот, в `Json` ответе я получаю `user_id` этого пользователя.

Вопрос: Мне делать отдельный запрос для получения данных о пользователе в методе `onResponse` запроса для диалогов, где комментарий `//Действие при успешном запросе`? И вообще таких моментов очень много оказывается в `VK-API`, как делать запросы в таких случаях, одновременно?

Comment: Точно одновременно надо сделать? Или всё же последовательно, после получения ID?

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то можно взять либу rxJava и сделать в 5 строк так: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/729543/17609

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, ну как, желательно одновременно, как сам ВК делает, при запуске приложения, вроде бы сразу же загружает и аватарки

Comment: А без RX не получится? Так как я не знаком с ним. Или можно изучить быстренько для такого рода задач?

Comment: Судя по описанию апи без отдельного запроса не получится. Без rx можно, но сложно и муторно. Возможно сложнее и муторнее чем изучить великолепный rx

Comment: Как же я не хотел сталкиваться с ним)

Comment: И очень зря) С ним жить лучше и веселее)

Comment: )Что посоветуете для быстрого старта?

Comment: Право, не знаю. Возможно серию статей "грокаем rxjava" на хабре

Comment: ой случайно начал на чат. Спасибо

Comment: Помимо этого цикла статей, рекомендую платный курс на сайте startandroid.ru . Все просто, понятно и по полочкам